# i'm getting out of shape left bicep cause weight is not acting on my left bicep

Tags: upper-body-workout

I am from India. My problem is that my left hand is quite bent, so weight is not acting properly on my left hand. My left bicep looks a bit smaller and looser than the right one. When i do chin ups, my left hand goes outwards, which is the reason for no action of weight. Please suggest some tips so that I can straighten up my hand and do workouts without any worry. I need exercises which add effect on my left bicep and make both the biceps even.

Comment: When you say that your hand is "bent", do you mean that it's turned sideways? And do you know the source of this bend? Was it a birth condition? Injury? Stroke?

Comment: For what it sounds like, you really should be checked out by a medical provider before you start a routine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reference handy, but somewhere in [Arnold: The Education of a Bodybuilder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0751515752), Arnold noticed that though he was doing the same volume on both arms, his left arm was lagging, so he would do unilateral exercises for it, e.g. one day a week do dumbbell curls with just the left arm.

Would doing extra left-arm curls work for you, or is there something about your left hand that would prevent that from being effective?